# can not load the calendar widget from investing.com

Tags: iframe, calendar, widget

I have generated the html code from using this url(https://www.investing.com/webmaster-tools/economic-calendar)  to add the calendar to my site. They have provided the following code

```
<iframe src="https://sslecal2.forexprostools.com?columns=exc_flags,exc_currency,exc_importance,exc_actual,exc_forecast,exc_previous&features=datepicker,timezone&countries=25,32,6,37,72,22,17,39,14,10,35,43,56,36,110,11,26,12,4,5&calType=week&timeZone=8&lang=1" width="650" height="467" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe><div class="poweredBy" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 11px;color: #333333;text-decoration: none;">Real Time Economic Calendar provided by <a href="https://www.investing.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="font-size: 11px;color: #06529D; font-weight: bold;" class="underline_link">Investing.com</a>.</span></div>
```

But when I am adding this in my website (in a Laravel blade file) I am getting the following window.

[image]

instead of getting  the following
[image]

does anyone have the similar experience? would be really helpful if can provide any solution.

Comment: hey, did you find a solution to that problem ?

Comment: Hi, so far I remember I did not get any solution for that. It’s something on their side, you can contact with them.

Comment: I contacted them but I fixed this before, the issue was because I was using a local server. Once I passed it into production, so on a remote server, it was fixed

Comment: Thats great. Thank you for letting me know.